# Computation failed in `stat_alluvium()`: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data.frame that was built with a collection of Tidyverse tools, mostly dplyr stuff with piping.  The data looks formatted correctly for the geom_flow() examples that you can find for ggalluvial.  My dataset undergoes a pile of iterations after its imported from an MSSQL database and is around 300k rows.  So I created a dummy version of it that reports all the same classes and formats when I start setting it up for ggalluvial, I also did this to see if the error was recreatable on a smaller scale to better troubleshoot.

```
data <- data.frame(Employee = as.numeric(c(1450,1450,1450,1450,1460,1460,1460,1460,1470,1470)),
                  PostDate = as.POSIXct(c("2019-08-15","2019-09-12","2019-09-15","2019-10-12","2019-08-15","2019-09-12","2019-09-15","2019-10-12","2019-08-15","2019-09-12")),
                  Job = as.character(c("1901", "1901","1902","1902","1901", "1901","1902","1902","1901", "1901")),
                  Phase = as.character(c("950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-")),
                  Craft = as.character(c("Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab")),
                  Class = as.character(c("1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B")),
                  EarnCode  = as.numeric(c("51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51")),
                  Hours = as.numeric(c(8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 12, 3, 8, 9)),
                  Rate = as.numeric(c(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50)),
                  Amt = as.numeric(c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)),
                  LastName = as.character(c("bill", "bill", "bill", "bill", "mike", "mike", "mike", "mike", "joe", "joe")),
                  FirstName = as.character(c("bill", "bill", "bill", "bill", "mike", "mike", "mike", "mike", "joe", "joe")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Most of the columns are eliminated quickly but to get the data down to how I want it for ggalluvial I apply the following tidyverse stuff to:

```
df_data_Aluv <- data %>%
        filter(PostDate >= "2019-08-01" & PostDate <= "2019-10-30") %>%
        select(date = PostDate, Employee, Job, Hours) %>%
        group_by(Job, month = as.character(floor_date(date, "month")), Employee) %>%
        distinct(month, Job, Employee, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
        summarize(freq = n_distinct(Employee))
```

The idea is to get the count of employees summarized by month for a count and sankey diagram.  The ploting code I expect work is:

```
ggplot(df_data_Aluv,
           aes(x = month, 
               stratum = Job, 
               alluvium = Employee,
               y = freq,
               fill = Job, 
               label = Job)) +
        scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.1, .1)) +
        geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", 
                  lode.guidance = "frontback",
                  color = "darkgray") +
        geom_stratum(alpha = .5) +
        geom_text(stat = "stratum", size = 3) +
        theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
        ggtitle("Project month responses at three points in time")
```

preEdit Edit: well I was typing this up I noticed Job was creating a condition where an employee was to be counted in two locations of each bar of the graph.  I figured this might be part of the problem so I rejiggered my test data and tested changing to the following data:

```
        data <- data.frame(Employee = as.numeric(c(1450,1450,1450,1450,1460,1460,1460,1460,1470,1470)),
                       PostDate = as.POSIXct(c("2019-08-15","2019-08-12","2019-09-15","2019-10-12","2019-08-15","2019-08-12","2019-09-15","2019-10-12","2019-08-15","2019-09-12")),
                       Job = as.character(c("1901", "1901","1902","1902","1901", "1901","1902","1902","1901", "1901")),
                       Phase = as.character(c("950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-", "950-")),
                       Craft = as.character(c("Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab", "Lab")),
                       Class = as.character(c("1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B", "1B")),
                       EarnCode  = as.numeric(c("51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51")),
                       Hours = as.numeric(c(8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 12, 3, 8, 9)),
                       Rate = as.numeric(c(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50)),
                       Amt = as.numeric(c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)),
                       LastName = as.character(c("bill", "bill", "bill", "bill", "mike", "mike", "mike", "mike", "joe", "joe")),
                       FirstName = as.character(c("bill", "bill", "bill", "bill", "mike", "mike", "mike", "mike", "joe", "joe")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I was able to reworked my dplyr stuff so ether one would succeed, Effectively picking which Job the Employee should be counted towards during a given month, filtered on max Hours, so after this change both example data sets work with this code:

```
    df_data_Aluv <- data %>%
        filter(PostDate >= "2019-08-01" & PostDate <= "2019-10-30") %>%
        select(date = PostDate, Employee, Job, Hours) %>%
        group_by(Job, month = as.character(floor_date(date, "month")), Employee) %>%
        summarize(freq = n_distinct(Employee), Hours = sum(Hours)) %>%
        group_by(Employee, month) %>%
        filter(Hours == max(Hours))
```

So, I go back to my original 300k row dataset, and apply the dplyr steps to it, and where before I was getting a reduced data frame of 287 and an error message of

```
Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 287 rows:
\* 1, 2
\* 3, 4
\* 5, 6
 ... (lists ever row this way)
```

Now I'm getting the same reduction to 287 rows, but now the error is

```
Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 1 rows:
\* 109, 110
```

Going and looking at those two rows in Rstudios View(), I can't see why it's still flagging them as shared keys.

```php
    106 1906-   2019-10-01  4267    1   91.5;
    107 1906-   2019-10-01  4317    1   119.0
    108 1907-   2019-08-01  582     1   406.0
    109  1907-   2019-08-01  705     1   396.0
    110  1907-   2019-08-01  1224    1   229.5
    111 1907-   2019-08-01  1700    1   179.5
    112 1907-   2019-08-01  1744    1   235.0
    113 1907-   2019-08-01  1959    1   234.5
```

Any further suggestions to avoid this error would be very helpful.  I found searching for it very frustrating since the vast majority of search result are for spread() and not obviously related.  Could be one of my dplyr or the ggalluvial commands are using it a few layers deep, but its not at a level I can troubleshoot.

Is there a good way to avoid the error upfront?  Why is my row 109 and 110 still flagging as duplicate when clearly they don't duplicate each other.  This will be going into a shiny app eventually, so my solution needs to be robust for a user input date range.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not satisfied with this solution, but it's at least working.  The two variables I want to group on just wont work having  group_by(Employee, month) %>% so I added a mutate, to only group but the mutated combined variable, then use distinct to make sure that combined variable has no duplicates.

```
    df_data_Aluv <- data %>%
        filter(PostDate >= "2019-08-01" & PostDate <= "2019-10-30") %>%
        select(date = PostDate, Employee, Job, Hours) %>%
        group_by(Job, month = as.character(floor_date(date, "month")), Employee) %>%
        summarize(freq = n_distinct(Employee), Hours = sum(Hours)) %>%
        mutate(empmon = paste(Employee, " -- ", month)) %>%
        group_by(empmon) %>%
        filter(Hours == max(Hours)) %>%
        distinct(empmon, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

it works for any date range, so I got what I wanted at least

[image]